# Error when connecting to database in unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application. The application runs perfectly. I can view, add, update and delete records, but when I run the unit tests, it shows an error on every test method.

The error is:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

Error details:

> {"Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=21013; handshake=0; "}

What can be issue?

Unit Test Code

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Company_GetCompanyType()
{
    controllerBuilder.Session["loggedEmpId"] = 6;
    companyId = 66;

    //Case 1 : Does  Company have Type or not ?
    JsonResult actualCompanyType = oCompanyController.GetCompanyType(companyId) as JsonResult;          
    var result = actualCompanyType.Data;           
    Assert.IsNull(result,"Company have types");        
}
```

Comment: That you're actually trying to connect to your data store in a unit test rather than mocking it

Comment: means ? Not getting...

Comment: Can you show some of your unit test code? It will help to see how you're approaching the testing. It sounds like your unit tests are hitting the real database, which they shouldn't be

Comment: I will update in the Question please check...

Comment: I have updated the question , please check

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an answer/solution to your actual problem, but a good tip in general.

I strongly recommend not hitting the DB in every unit test, the same applies to the file system and other slow IO operations.
Use a simple pattern like the [Repository Pattern](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/) to abstract away the data access. You can then either implement a fake repository (i.e. backed by a `List<T>`) or use a mocking framework like [moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/) to setup a mocked repository.

By doing this, your tests will run completely in-memory and thus run much faster. You also don't need to care about connection strings and that you always have access to the database.

Answer (score -1):

Unit Test, use don't hit the database.  You use a mocking framework like Moq or RhinoMocks.  If you are wanting to hit the database this is calling an integration test.

Integration test are very time consuming, so tons of these cannot end up running through the night hours on automation , but a handful of them are good.

Based on the code that I see above, I would test this with a console application or linqpad if you are having trouble, otherwise the TestMethod is going to be timely to troubleshoot.